# sql 3 tables union

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

I have three tables:

`Container` with fields are `ContainerNo`, `Date` ,

and a table :
`Order` with fields: `ConteunrNo`, `Customer`

and the third table is
  `Purchase` with field `ConteunrNo`, `Customer`.

All tables are linked with the Container No.

I want to make a Union query that show
`ConainerNo` , `Customer`.

That will include all record from all tables.

And that will work with php later because I heard some complaining about union queries working in phpmyadmin but not in PHP
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a union all  a an inner join

```
select ContainerNo , Customer
from Order 
inner join  Container.ContainerNo =   Order.ContainerNo 
union all
select ContainerNo , Customer
from Purchase 
inner join  Container.ContainerNo =   Purchase.ContainerNo
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
Select ConteunrNo as 'ContainerNo' , Customer  FROM Order 
Union all
Select ConainerNo   as 'ContainerNo', Customer FROM  Purchase
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just union them together:

```
select containerNo, Customer
from orders
union all
select containerNo, Customer
from purchase;
```